# plugin to organize data

Tags: plugins

I am currently converting [this](http://www.dafp.de/Publikationen/publ_jour.htm#A) page into a wordpress site. Now as you can see on the page I linked to, I need some sort of way to organize the data on the site. I have already looked for a plugin for the job but I can´t find the right thing. can someone suggest a plugin that could do the job?

things that the plugin should do:

- let the admin add more data into pre defined fields through backend
- add the new data into the appropriate position on the site (sort alphabetic by name)
- alpha index at the top to quickly jump to desired letter in alphabet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good plugin afterall:

[post index](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-index/)

this plugin makes it easy to create a list with an alphaindex from articels from a specific category. just make a new page, put the shortcode from the plugin which specifies the category on it and its done. all article from that category are now added to the list. the article names are sorted alphabetically and link to the actual post. just what I neede, maybe somebody else is looking for something like this as well. you can see it here in action (temporarily) [link](http://k-im.de/dafp/home/lexikon/)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this yourself using a custom post type for the data and a custom taxonomy for the name tied together by a custom template to show it all. If you are unfamiliar with CPTs or CTs, you can find generators [here](http://themergency.com/generators/) that will help you get started.

Comment: If you decided to go with the custom post type, custom taxonomy, custom field route, then this is a simple, easy to use plugin that will get the job done. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/